# PySimpleGUI: How to select an image from file browser and save to another folder

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Is there a simple way to select an image from the file browser, view it, and then move it to another folder using PySimpleGUI? I have the code for selecting an image but I don't know how to view it and move to another folder.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io
import sys

# Get the file for test image
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    fname = sg.popup_get_file('Select Image To Use as TestImage', default_path='')
else:
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    
if not fname:
    sg.popup_cancel('Cancelling')
    raise SystemExit()
else:
    sg.popup('The file chosen is', fname)
```

This is the code for selecting an image.

How can I view in my UI and move the selected image to another folder. Sort of like uploading an image and storing it on a server(like in social media platforms).

Answer (score 1):

Using method `popup_get_file` to get filename to open, and `popup_get_folder` to get which directory to move file to.

Using `Image` element to show the image, maybe also library `PIL.Image` to fit the size of image.

Demo code for it, here not specified the default path when browse file or browse directory.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def update_image(image_element, filename):
    if not Path(filename).is_file():
        return
    try:
        im = Image.open(filename)
    except:
        return
    width, height = size_of_image
    scale = max(im.width/width, im.height/height)

    if scale > 1:
        w, h = int(im.width/scale), int(im.height/scale)
        im = im.resize((w, h), resample=Image.CUBIC)

    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    image_element.update(data=data)

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 11))

w, h = size_of_image = (600, 600)

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Open'), sg.Button('Move'), sg.Input(expand_x=True, disabled=True, key='Filename')],
    [sg.Image(background_color='green', size=size_of_image, key='-IMAGE-', expand_x=True, expand_y=True)],
]

window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout, size=(800, 800), enable_close_attempted_event=True, finalize=True)
filename = None

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event == 'Open':
        filename = sg.popup_get_file("", no_window=True)
        if filename:
            update_image(window['-IMAGE-'], filename)
            window['Filename'].update(filename)
    elif event == 'Move':
        if filename and Path(filename).is_file():
            old_directory = Path(filename).parent
            directory = sg.popup_get_folder("", no_window=True)
            if directory and Path(directory).is_dir():
                if Path(directory) != old_directory:
                    new_path = Path(directory).joinpath(Path(filename).name)
                    Path(filename).replace(new_path)
                    filename = str(new_path)
                    window['Filename'].update(filename)

window.close()
```